# How do I take a long screenshot in Linux?

Tags: screenshot

I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to take a screenshot of a long reddit comment to save it later in the note-taking app Obsidian. The default screenshot app in Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't offer that option as of now.I looked up for linux apps that could do it but couldn't find any. Is there a screenshot app for linux that allows long-screenshots or maybe a possible workaround?

Comment: I think you should use the facilities provided by the application. If this is a web browser like Firefox, look at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/take-screenshots-firefox

Comment: Firefox has a built-in screenshot facility. I took this https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqeLT.jpg just now using it

Answer (score 3):

The default browser of Ubuntu, Firefox, can do this. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or select "Take screenshot" from the right-click menu on an empty part of the page, and you will be offered to save a selection or the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

In **Chrome**, you can inspect your desired element (hit **F12** and go to the **Elements tab**), find the element which contains all the content you want to screenshot from, then right-click on the target HTML element and select `Capture node screenshot` from the context menu.

It will create a long screenshot for you with great quality.